# Does every nonzero Turing degree adimit a nonzero incompatible degree?

Tags: logic, computability

It is well known that every nonzero Turing degree $\bf x$ adimits an incomparable degree $\bf y$, that is a degree such that $\bf x\not\le_T\bf y$ and $\bf y\not\le_T\bf x$.

I was wondering whether this statement generalizes to the stronger following one: every nonzero Turing degree $\bf x$ adimits a nonzero degree $\bf y$ which is incompatible with it, meaning that the set $\{\bf x,\bf y\}$ has no nonzero lower bounds.

In case this statement were known to be false, is it known exactly what degrees provide counterexamples to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every degree has this property. Specifically, for every Turing degree **d** there is a *minimal* Turing degree **a** not below **d** (in particular, any sufficiently-Sacks-generic real will have this property, with "sufficiently" depending on **d**).

Alternatively, we can do a *single* forcing and produce a perfect set of Turing incomparable minimal degrees; since any Turing degree only computes countably many things, this immediately implies that for every degree **d** there is a minimal **a** not below **d**.

It's worth keeping in mind that the minimal degrees display far more variety and structure than one might guess. In particular, "minimal" does not really mean "small" - for example, for any **d$\ge_T0'$**  there is some minimal **a** such that **a**$'=$ **d**. (This is [due to Cooper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272061).) Similarly, for any degrees **d, x** there is some minimal **a** such that **a** $\vee$ **d** $=$ **x** (and this strengthens the affirmative answer to your question given above).

And I can't end without mentioning an interesting open questions about the minimal degrees (I believe each due to Yates). Say that **a** is a **strong minimal cover** of **d** if **a** $\ge_T$ **d** and every degree $<_T$ **a** is $\le_T$ **d**. *(By contrast, a minimal cover simply satisfies $($**d**, **a**$)=\emptyset$.)* Yates asked - and I believe this is still completely open - whether every minimal Turing degree has a strongly minimal cover. It is known meanwhile that every *sufficiently large* Turing degree has a strongly minimal cover, and that there are Turing degrees without strongly minimal covers, so really either answer is plausible.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, Noah! And shame on me that I didn't figure it out! In my defence, I didn't really know that, given any degree, it is possible to find a minimal degree incomparable with it (even though I should have expected that). Though, I'm still wondering what happens if you ask the nonzero incompatible degree to be non-minimal, too...

Comment: @V.Bard Thanks, I'm glad I could help! Re: your final question, yes, you can get that too. Indeed, for any countable partial order $P$ with a least element and any nonzero degree **d** there is a set $X$ of degrees which $(i)$ is isomorphic to $P$ under $\le_T$ and $(ii)$ each element of which is incomparable with **d**. So you can basically get minimal pairs of any "shape" you want.

Comment: You helped a lot, your answer was very informative! Regarding your comment: I don't see how to use the fact you mention to get incompatibility with $\bf d$...

Comment: @V.Bard Whoops, sorry, I also meant to add that $X$ is an initial segment of the Turing degrees.

Comment: If by "initial" you mean that $X$ is a whole interval between a minimal degree and some other degree then that's fine... thanks!

Comment: @V.Bard No, there need be no minimal degrees in $X$ at all - I just mean that $X$ is closed downwards.

Comment: Ok, closed downward but should not contain $\bf 0$, right? Otherwise, how could $X$ satisfy that its every element is incomparable with $\bf d$?

Comment: @V.Bard $X$ does contain ${\bf 0}$, I meant to write "every *nonzero* element of $X$ is incomparable with **d**."

Comment: Got it, thanks!